# Override LESS variable in CSS selector

Tags: css, less

I'm looking for a method to override a LESS variable within a CSS selector.
Example below doesn't work:

```
@main: #01b2bb;

body.purple{
   @main: #937cb8;
}
#wrapper header{background-color: @main}
```

I expected **#937cb8** as output when body have class purple.

Comment: Do you get an error?  I have put it through http://www.lesstester.com and it compiled correctly.

Comment: See my post again.
The output is: #01b2bb instead of #937cb8

Comment: Why are you trying to override it this way?

Comment: The less that you have provided compiles correctly.  I'm not sure this is the issue.  Have you checked the compiled css?  Or is it an issue where your style is being overridden?  More detail please.

Comment: Variables in Less just don't work that way. Less has no notion of HTML so it can't know what sort of `body` your `#header` is in (so `#header` can't inherit the variable defined in `body`). See [Scope](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope). You'll get what you want with: `.purple #wrapper header {background-color: #937cb8}`

Answer (score 2):

### Commonly

Often with LESS, one would have different variable files to serve up *a different set of css (a different file)* for, as in your case, the `body.purple` css, where `@main` is originally defined globally in the variable file with `#937cb8` (and so it is the "purple" variable file). This keeps the css code reduced, but does require one to serve up a new file on class change of `body`.

### Optionally

If, however, you want class distinction all within a single css file, then it probably is better to abstract the code out more, where something like this would keep it more manageable by keeping all the color defining within one mixin:

**LESS**

```css
.setColors() {
  @main: #01b2bb; //default     
  .purple & {
    @main: #937cb8;
    .setCss();
  }
  .red & {
    @main: #ff0000;
    .setCss();
  }
  .blue & {
    @main: #0000ff;
    .setCss();
  }
}

#wrapper header {
  .setColors();
  .setCss() {
    background-color: @main;
  }
}

.myListClass {
  .setColors();
  .setCss() {
    li {
      background-color: fade(@main, .5);
    }
    > a {
      color: @main;
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.purple #wrapper header {
  background-color: #937cb8;
}
.red #wrapper header {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.blue #wrapper header {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
.purple .myListClass li {
  background-color: rgba(147, 124, 184, 0.005);
}
.purple .myListClass > a {
  color: #937cb8;
}
.red .myListClass li {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.005);
}
.red .myListClass > a {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.blue .myListClass li {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.005);
}
.blue .myListClass > a {
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

Now this will append a color class to the front of anything using a color, which will then create css to change the color depending upon that parent class. Note that anything expecting to use color must call the `setColors();` mixin, and then must define that changing color css within a `.setCss()` mixin locally defined (as shown above). This is just one way of getting css to output for various parent classes controlling color.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `background-color` property for the purple class:

```
@main: #01b2bb;

body.purple{
   @main: #937cb8;
   background-color: @main;
}
#wrapper header{background-color: @main}
```